# bash add property in file json using variable with jq

Tags: json, shell, jenkins, jenkins-pipeline

this is the code :

```
pipeline {
  agent any
  stages {
    stage('parse') {
       steps {
          script{
              sh "jq -n ${params.name} ${params.version} >fichier.json"
           }
        }
     }     
  }
}
```

this is the output error:

```
jq:
```

```
error: test/0 is not defined at <top-level>, line 1:
test
jq: 1 compile error
```

ps:test is the return of params name

Comment: What contents do you want `fichier.json`  to have as a result? Right now, your command uses the value of `${params.name}` as the `jq` filter and `${params.version}` as a an additional, ignored argument (because of the `-n` option).

Comment: i do a Build with Parameters and i want this parameters output in file json , in this case i remove jq and i try this script `script{
                    sh " echo '[{"name":\"${name}\","version":\"${version}\"}]' > file.json"}` and i have this **error Syntax error: Unterminated quoted string**